# Reactive vs. declarative approach: which is most commonly used in Angular?

Tags: angular, reactive-programming

I have one year experience as a frontend developer and I mainly use Angular. My understanding of reactive and declarative programming in Angular is still rather shallow.

**My question is**: Which approach is more widespread? The reactive approach (especially reified reactive) or the declarative approach?

P/s: The reason I ask is that there are only a couple of FE developers at my workplace, and they all use the declarative approach. After learning more about "reactive programming", I think this approach should be the common approach for Angular developers (just my opinion). It's quite confusing that I don't see anyone using this approach at my workplace.

Comment: It really depends..Reactive programming can add a lot of complexity and overhead to your code if you don't truly need it, and in a lot of cases, you don't *really* need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most developers use the Reactive Approach. Reactive programming describes a design paradigm that relies on asynchronous programming logic to handle real-time updates to otherwise static content.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can definitively say "Most developers use the Reactive Approach" - maybe most developers you know, but certainly you do not know nor represent the Angular developer community as a whole. Do you have any data or statistics to back up this assertion, or is this simply coming from your opinion?